# Javascript search an element with a max value from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string in javascript which is made of HTML. In that there are various element which has a `top` attribute. What I want to do is that I need to get the top element with the maximum value. What i tried approaching is that I tried a `search()` and `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` but the top element with max attribute can lie anywhere.So what should be my ideal approach towards this problem be?Thanks in advance

Example String:`style=\"left: 200; top: 10; width: ; height: ; position: absolute; display: none; \"  title='...' >...</BUTTON><span  style=\"position:absolute;left:10px;top:35px;\" "`

Here I have 2 top attributes, but in the real string i will have more.So how should I get the top attribute with max value?

Comment: Try using the DOM. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Comment: Please click "edit" and add an example string to your question. (And then do what elclanrs said.)

Comment: Folks Please give some example of html string.

Comment: Will DOM help me searching an element from a string
?I just need to et the maximum value of the top from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx, like this

```
var data = 'style="left: 200; top: 10; width: ; height: ; position: absolute; display: none; \"></BUTTON><span  style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:35px;"';
var regex = /top\s*:\s*(\d+)/ig;
var match = regex.exec(data);
var maximum = parseInt(match[1], 10), temp = 0;
while((match = regex.exec(data)) !== null) {
    temp = parseInt(match[1], 10);
    if (temp > maximum) {
        maximum = temp;
    }
}
console.log(maximum);
# 35
```