# javascript-Getting the height attribute of an element which has maximum top

Tags: javascript, css

I need to get the height attribute of an element which has a maximum top.I will get the maximum top of an element as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23380192/1605834)

The html code for the same would be quite similar to the one shown below.

```
style=\"left: 200; top: 10; width: ; height:50 ; position: absolute; display: none; \"  title='...' >...</BUTTON><span  style=\"position:absolute;height:500;left:10px;top:35px;\" "
```

So how can I get the height attribute for the same.In the above string I should get the height as 500 since top:35 is the maximum of two.I may have n number of  elements in the string containing those parameters.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets pretend you have a div, or really any element with those active styles on it:

```
<div id='attr' ></div>
```

To get an attribute of an element is really simple. There are multiple ways to do this.

First:

```
document.getElementById('attr').getAttribute('height');
```

Which should return its current height.

You can also do the same thing using another method, assuming you know what element you are looking for:

`document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('height');` Which would do the same thing. The [0] index number just means its the first div element.

Also I reccomend specifying your measurements of styles with a unit, such as % or px. Although there are tons of other units out there.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I dont know the element, I will just get to know the maximum top, so how can the get the height of the element whose top I have just identified, without knowing the element?

Comment: Do you mean like an `if` statement that would check every child node attribute of height and see if it was equal to the certain height you specified? @Nilesh

Comment: No,I would get the maximum top..eg:in the above string the top with maximum value is 35..and the corresponding height of that element is 500.I need that height of the element whose top i have just extracted.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. You mean the one with the 35 or the one with the 500? Im not sue what I am missing @Nilesh

Comment: Ok lets take the string above.With the help of the url given above I get the valoe of the top which is maximum i.e 35.I do not get the element then only the value of the top.I just need to get height of the element knowing the top of that element being 35.I do not know the element.